# Specific AmE term for chiefly BrE "workmate" other than "fellow worker", "coworker", and "colleague"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, vocabulary

Is there a close synonym in modern day AmE for what is referred to in BrE as a workmate?

Aside from being current, I wish I could get a term that is idiomatic with no space or hyphen, that would sit somewhere between "coworker" and "work pal" on the intimacy scale, and that would come right after "fellow worker" on the formality one.

> http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workmate
>
> !http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Mate?s=t

Please consider this ngram [source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=workmate%2Ccoworker%2Cfellow+worker&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworkmate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoworker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfellow%20worker%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Work friend or work pal?

Comment: Most natural would probably be a _friend from work_.

Comment: @Ronan Thanks for your suggestions, but actually I'm looking for a word less intimate than "work pal" and "work friend", and ideally with no space or hyphen by analogy with "workmate".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Coworker" might actually be the term that fits best. What do you think?

Comment: Don't Americans say 'workmate'? They use 'room-mate'.

Comment: Exactly, can you not just use workmate?

Comment: @WS2 Apparently not. They indeed say "room mate", and "schoolmate", "classmate", and "seatmate" also. But the term "workmate' is chiefly BE in the sense "coworker".

Comment: @Ronan Check this out http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=465590

Comment: @NourishedGourmet I understand that it's not a common term, but I'd imagine no American would be confused by it or its meaning.

Comment: @Ronan I quite agree with you on this. But I'm looking for a term that is idiomatic to AmE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Americans in general say:

- 'coworker' for someone they work with, no friendliness (or lack of friendliness) implied
- 'officemate' for someone you share an office with
- 'friend at work' for someone they get along well with at work. This isn't a set phrase. It is very literal meaning they are chummy at work but aren't necessarily friends outside of work.

'Workmate' is just not used in  AmE.

Which is all to say I don't think there is an exact translation of 'workmate' to AmE. Of course, since I am not a BrE speaker, I'm not exactly sure of the nuances of 'workmate' other than it is somewhat foreign to me.

Comment: I agree that *workmate* isn't used in AmE, at least not in the Midwest. Americans also use the words *associate* and *colleague* for coworkers, especially in business/office/professional settings.